# Tails on live USB flash drive freezes

Tags: usb, freeze, tor, liveusb, tails

I'm testing [Tails 4.6](https://tails.boum.org) on a [Terra USThree 32 GB USB 3.0](https://terra-it-systeme.de/terra-usthree-usb3-0-32gb-white-read-write-120-15-mb-s-2191278/) flash drive. The host system is an IBM ThinkPad R60 with 3 GB RAM.

When loading multiple script-heavy websites on the bundled Tor browser or editing moderately-sized images with the bundled Gimp editor, the system quickly slows down, often to a point where it gets stuck in a permanent "overload cycle" indefinitely (mouse cursor gets stuck for a few seconds, moves again, gets stuck again etc.) or even slows down to a complete and permanent freeze, both usually requiring a forced reboot.

How can this be allowed to happen? I understand that the USB connection can be a bottleneck between Tails running on the stick and the host's CPU, RAM etc. that it uses. But shouldn't system stability have *absolute god-like priority* over any possible app that might be running?

FWIW, I'm experiencing a similar behaviour with the Android Tor browser on my mobile phone. It frequently consumes most of the CPU/RAM (heavy lagging when scrolling etc.) - until I simply cut the data connection, which immediately frees up CPU/RAM. Is this normal behaviour or could this be malware-related?

Comment: The phone question is better suited at Android-SE I think. You should add the specs of the computer the USB is plugged into.... Or It could just be bad flash space causing this on the usb, it happened to me recently with a persistent live boot Ubuntu image I was using. It had these symptoms for three consecutive boots, then halted booting with file system errors and corrupted files. The USB was the culprit...

Comment: Please edit your question to add the specific make and model of your USB flash drive. “Fairly speedy 32 GB USB 2.0” What does that mean? I have used many supposedly “good” USB 2.0 flash drives and quality varies wildly.

Comment: Thanks, I appended those information. And it's actually USB 3.0, although I doubt that this is supported by the R60.

Comment: Hellooo........

Comment: Helloo, hellooo.....

Comment: HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEELLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO